# How to use aws cognito response_code form saml redirect to get user info from cognito?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito, saml

How do you use the code returned from SAML idp with aws cognito to retrieve user information from cognito?

The original link that the SP uses is.

```
https://some-subdomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/login?response_type=code&client_id=some-client-id&redirect_uri=https://some-api-gateway-subdomain.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v1/some-endpoint
```

Then the ipd does the auth, then redirects to sp.

```
 https://some-api-gateway-subdomain.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/dev/api/v1/some-endpoint?code=12345
```

How do I use the 12345 to get the user info from cogito.

I saw I could hit the

```
https://some-subdomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/token
```

to get a token(s).  I did not set an app secret, so need for bearer token according to https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/token-endpoint.html (I realize this is for oauth, but did not find any docs talking about how to use the response code specifically for saml interactions.)

However, when i try to get the token, passing the grant_type, client_id, code, redirect_uri, I get

```
{
    "error": "unauthorized_client"
}
```

If I was able to get the token(s) I could then use the token(s) to hit

```
https://some-subdomain.auth.us-east-1.amazoncognito.com/oauth2/userInfo
```

to get user information from cogito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the redirect_url for getting the token was not the same as the redirect for the saml auth.  Once I made it the same, everything worked.